# Rails global variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, global-variables

Im using bootstrap & rails and have a user model and post model..users create posts (collections)..

with bootstrap in the navbar i want the user to be able to click a dropdown which displays the name's of their posts..i did this on one controller with a private method and a before_action but i don't want to do this for all the controllers and it didn't work for the application controller...

is there a better way to do this??

I was doing this

```
def list
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  @collections = @user.collections
end
```

and a

```
before_action :list
```

at the top of the controller

What's the most semantic way to accomplish this??

Comment: "it didn't work for the application controller", what do you mean with this? any error? something? if the action/filter is something "global" that needs to be run for any action it should go as a before_action/filter in ApplicationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this in the application controller

```
before_action :list

private

  def list
    @collections = current_user.collections
  end
```

thanks @arieljuod

Answer (score 2):

If you could move both to your application controller, then it would be available to any controller. More generally, I'm not sure if this is the best approach to solve your problem.

These tips might also be useful.

1. Are you using devise? Or some other authentication plugin? If so you're likely going to have a `current_user` helper.  This would allow you to simply do `@collections = current_user.collections`
2. To the extent possible, I recommend using more descriptive names for your actions and parameters.  `def fetch_list_collections` might be a better name or instead of passing a param named `id`, perhaps your param should be named `username`.  These naming conventions become extremely important both for others who might look at your code as well as for yourself if you return to it and are trying to remember what you wrote N months ago.
3. Your list action is generating a N+1 queries.  Meaning that you're hitting the database multiple times when you should do so just once.  See the rails guide on this.  You might also look at ways to avoid this w/ devise.  Devise is pretty well documented and I'll bet there is something in the wiki discussing this.
4. You may want to consider limiting when you call this action - at a minimum - a post request to an update action?  What about before they've logged in? current_user might be `nil` and you'd have an error attempting to call a `collections` method on `nil`.

Take your time learning this stuff.  You don't have to learn it all at once, but I thought the above might be helpful.