# "NoMethodError in OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook: undefined method `utc' for Mon, 29 Sep 2014:Date" from Devise using Rails and MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, mongodb, devise

I've spent my free time over the last two weeks trying to get Facebook authentication working for VoteSquared.org ( https://github.com/ForestJay/VoteSquared ).  The sign_in_and_redirect is where the error is occurring:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def facebook
   # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
   @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

   if @user
     sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
     set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
     #redirect_to politicians_path
   else
     session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     redirect_to new_user_registration_url
   end
 end
end
```

I've been using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview as a guide (ie: that's where I got this code).  I know the user is being created (via debug calls).  Here is the top of the error stack:

```
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:189:in `confirmation_period_valid?'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:126:in `active_for_authentication?'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/hooks/activatable.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:14:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:14:in `block in _run_callbacks'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:9:in `each'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:9:in `_run_callbacks'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:53:in `_run_callbacks'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:179:in `set_user'
devise (3.3.0) lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb:43:in `sign_in'
```

The most related error I have found via Google is https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3078 .  I know that Devise is not recommended for new Rails developers, but Facebook is a must for this application.  One work-around I briefly tried was re-directing to another page as I know login already occurred and the user was created.  The problem with my work-around is that there seems to be no global variable I can use to access the User (which is related to [Rails global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372649/rails-global-variable) ).  Any advice is appreciated.  At this point, I really just need access to the User information after login so that I know they are logged in and can associate their user to other objects.

Looking at the Devise code, I realized that the field with the issue is User::confirmed_at .  Here is how I have that field defined in user.rb:

```
  key :confirmed_at, Time
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack of a solution, but it appears to get me past this crash (to yet another crash).  I changed the above code to the following:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user
      # The following line forces confirmed_at to be set so it doesn't crash in Devise's type conversion
      @user.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
      #redirect_to politicians_path
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

I'll use this solution for now, but I'd love a solution where I don't have to manually set the value.  I think it is best to let Devise do that work.